# How to target multiple classes in CSS on a Hero Row

Tags: css

first thing, I'm a hacker when it comes to CSS. Trying to read and practice as much as possible to get better. Currently, I'm trying to add a set of media queries to a row to control padding, margins, and font sizing from mobile up so my text is positioned exactly where I want it. My question is how do I create a class for a row, so these styles only apply to this row of content. In this case, it's the first(hero) row on my website that has html text over an image. Below is what I'm trying to write, give or take a couple fine tuning adjustments. How do I create a single class to control the styling of the h2 and h3 classes?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 481px) {
#wrapper .hero h2 {
    font-size: 36px!important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 481px) {
#wrapper .hero h3 {
    font-size: 22px!important;
  }
}
```

I appreciate any guidance or support the community can share!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 481px) {
#wrapper .hero h2 {
    font-size: 36px!important;
  }
#wrapper .hero h3 {
    font-size: 22px!important;
  }
}
```

Else you can use less or SASS preprocessor for control multiple property in single class

Answer (score 0):

From your CSS, it's clear that your want to apply different font size to different child elements in the same viewport. It will not be possible to define two values for same property i.e font-size in this case and expect the browser to use both for different elements. However, you need to define the media query only once:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 481px) {
#wrapper .hero h2 {
    font-size: 36px!important;
  }
#wrapper .hero h3 {
    font-size: 22px!important;
  }
}
```